# how to update the table from the new rows that come to another table every day in sql

Tags: sql, database

I have Table A and its connected to some server that give him the new transactions every day . I created a table B and inserted the data from table A, How I can write a query that make Table B get updated every day from table A with the new transactions.

I have not tried a query

Comment: You can use something called TRIGGER

Comment: Or replication, or synchronization. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If you haven't tried anything yet, why not change that? Share your attempts, such that others could see where it is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

have createdon and updatedon columns on both tables and update the columns whenever records are inserted and updated. This way createdon,updateon columns can be used to retrieve the records

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).